# Does javax.annotation.Nonnull affect runtime behavior at all?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm wondering if annotating a parameter with `@Nonnull` affects runtime behavior at all, or if it's strictly used for static analysis.

Comment: Annotations generally don’t affect the behavior of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSR-305](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305) has

> Status: Dormant

and the question about the status on the [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsr-305/4vqYTAuWncY) remains unanswered. So there is no "official" application for it, it's just some tools (like Findbugs) that can perform static analysis depending on it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the this is only checked at compile-time.

From [Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_s_new_type):

> @NonNull – The compiler can determine cases where a code path might receive a null value, without ever having to debug a NullPointerException.

Comment: If I read that correctly, it refers to `org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull` and not to `javax.annotation.Nonnull`, doesn't it?

Comment: It's hard to even tell for sure.  Oracle's documentation is pathetic.

Comment: Right, that particular paragraph gives **examples** for type annotations based on work around the Checkers Framework. They also have a comprehensive list of annotations that express the same intention: http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#nullness-related-work . Indeed, all these are intended for static analysis. BTW: In a *fully checked* program no violations of null contracts can occur and hence at runtime nothing remains to be checked ...